# Trying to build an Android UI element in a library

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shared-libraries

I've spent the last two hours trying to figure out how to do this, and am coming up blank.  I've looked through many of the entries here on stackoverflow related to this...although I've tried to follow the fixes as written nothing has helped.  I think if I had a better understanding of how Java, Android, and Eclipse worked I could use the previous answers, but I'm going to need a more basic explanation.  Here's what I'm trying to do:  I've created an Android Library Project called AndroidUILibrary.  I can't post the image of what my Java Build Path window looks like (need 10 reputation points), but I am exporting both the src and gen folders from my project.

In this library project I have the following class:

```
public class FileDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activity = getActivity();
    activity.setContentView(R.id.fileDialogFragmentLinearLayout);
```

and the library's manifest looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sailbravado.androiduilibrary"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <library />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my Android Application I have the following code:

```
            final FileDialogFragment fileDialog = new FileDialogFragment();
            fileDialog.setCanSelectFiles(false);
            fileDialog.setOnClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                        logFolderValueTextView.setText(fileDialog.getSelectedFiles().get(0).getAbsolutePath());
                        logFolderValueTextView.setTag(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            fileDialog.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "");
```

In my Android application's Java Build Path I added AndroidUILibrary to the Projects tab, androiduilibrary.jar to the Libraries tab, and ensured that all entries are checked in Order and Export.  I then attempt to run the application.  The Console shows the following output:

```
[2014-09-20 18:45:03 - GPSLogger] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] ------------------------------
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] Android Launch!
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] Performing com.sailbravado.gpslogger.GPSLoggerActivity activity launch
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'E5ATCT027686'
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] Uploading GPSLogger.apk onto device 'E5ATCT027686'
[2014-09-20 18:45:04 - GPSLogger] Installing GPSLogger.apk...
[2014-09-20 18:45:07 - GPSLogger] Success!
[2014-09-20 18:45:07 - AndroidUILibrary] Could not find AndroidUILibrary.apk!
[2014-09-20 18:45:07 - GPSLogger] Starting activity com.sailbravado.gpslogger.GPSLoggerActivity on device E5ATCT027686
[2014-09-20 18:45:08 - GPSLogger] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.sailbravado.gpslogger/.GPSLoggerActivity }
```

When the "Dx" entry in the Console shows up, I notice a new folder gets created in my project hierarchy:  bin/dexedLibs.  It contains two JAR files...my androiduilibrary and appcompat_v7, both followed by a 32-digit hex number.  The application launches fine, but when I invoke the part that should create the dialog, I get:

```
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): Process: com.sailbravado.gpslogger, PID: 2739
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sailbravado.androiduilibrary.R$id
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.sailbravado.androiduilibrary.FileDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(FileDialogFragment.java:251)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:685)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
09-20 18:53:58.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2739):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Opening in the debugger, the exception is being thrown from the setContentView() call in the library code.

I tried adding a uses-library tag in the application's manifest, but I get:

```
[2014-09-20 18:02:51 - GPSLogger] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2014-09-20 18:02:51 - GPSLogger] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-20 18:02:51 - GPSLogger] Launch canceled!
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you go through "Setting up a library project" and "Referencing a library project" [over here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html)? From the looks of it, right now, you're basically referencing your library as a jar. That's fine as long as you don't need to access any resources. But in your case, you do, which is why you should reference it slightly different.

Comment: That worked...thanks!  I still get the "Could not find AndroidUILibrary.apk" message in the Console, but that doesn't seem to be affecting the proper execution of the code.